# Use sed to use "find and replace" for each second occurrence

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, text-editor

I have a folder with +1000 .dat files. And each file contains many lines of the following type:

```
-0.0999999999999659-0.0000000006287859
-0.08999999999997500.8000000006183942
-0.0799999999999841-0.0000000007463807
-0.06999999999999320.0000000008661516
-0.06000000000000230.0000000008640644
-0.05000000000001140.0000000008807621
-0.0400000000000205-0.7000000009575896
-0.02999999999997270.0000000009476864
-0.01999999999998180.0000000009150902
-0.00999999999999090.0000000008144152
0.00000000000000000.0000000007097434
0.00999999999999090.0000000007847500
0.01999999999998180.0000000009030998
0.03000000000002960.0000000009741985
```

For all the files I want to convert this to

```
-0.0999999999999659    -0.0000000006287859
-0.0899999999999750    0.8000000006183942
-0.0799999999999841    -0.0000000007463807
-0.0699999999999932    0.0000000008661516
-0.0600000000000023    0.0000000008640644
-0.0500000000000114    0.0000000008807621
-0.0400000000000205    -0.7000000009575896
-0.0299999999999727    0.0000000009476864
-0.0199999999999818    0.0000000009150902
-0.0099999999999909    0.0000000008144152
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000007097434
0.0099999999999909    0.0000000007847500
0.0199999999999818    0.0000000009030998
0.0300000000000296    0.0000000009741985
```

The only thing that is consistent in all these files that the second number (corresponding to the second dot on each line) is always smaller than 1.0 and greater than -1.0. But the first number can take any real value.

I therefore thought of using "find and replace" *only* for the second `dot' as follows. Find:

```
0.
```

Replace with:

```
   0.
```

I don't know how to specify `sed` only to act on the "second dot" on each line. Does anybody have a good idea on how to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 sed -E s'/(.*[^-])(-?0\.)/\1    \2/' 999.dat
```

The `*`  is greedy and eats up as much characters as possible so the `\.` matches always the last one of the line. The `[^-]` ensures that the optional `-` of the second number gets into the second group.

Comment: It is working with: find /home/folder -name \*.dat -exec sed -i -E s'/(.*[^-])(-?0\.)/\1    \2/' {} \; Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of work!

Answer (score 5):

To replace the second occurrence only, use the `2` modifier.  Thus:

```
$ sed -E 's/-?[[:digit:]][.]/    &/2' file.dat
-0.0999999999999659    -0.0000000006287859
-0.0899999999999750    0.8000000006183942
-0.0799999999999841    -0.0000000007463807
-0.0699999999999932    0.0000000008661516
-0.0600000000000023    0.0000000008640644
-0.0500000000000114    0.0000000008807621
-0.0400000000000205    -0.7000000009575896
-0.0299999999999727    0.0000000009476864
-0.0199999999999818    0.0000000009150902
-0.0099999999999909    0.0000000008144152
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000007097434
0.0099999999999909    0.0000000007847500
0.0199999999999818    0.0000000009030998
0.0300000000000296    0.0000000009741985
```

How it works:

- `-E`

  This tells sed to used extended regex.  This eliminates the need to escape the `?`.
- `s/-?[[:digit:]][.]/    &/2`

  This looks for an optional `-` followed by a digit followed by a literal `.`.  In the replacement text, four spaces are added before whatever the matched string, denoted `&`, is.

  The modifier `2` at the end of the substitute command tells sed to only replace the second occurrence of the pattern.

#### Related examples

Some more examples showing how different substitutions can be made:

```
$ echo aaaa | sed 's/a/A/1'
Aaaa
$ echo aaaa | sed 's/a/A/2'
aAaa
$ echo aaaa | sed 's/a/A/3'
aaAa
$ echo aaaa | sed 's/a/A/4'
aaaA
$ echo aaaa | sed 's/a/A/g'
AAAA
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm not sure why, but your solution is not working for me. I've used the following syntax: find /home/folder -name *.dat -exec sed -i -E s'/(.*[^-])(-?0\.)/\1 \2/' {} \;. Although it works for some lines, it skips many other lines.

Comment: The solution that you mention, `sed -i -E s'/(.*[^-])(-?0\.)/\1 \2/'`, is __not__ my solution.  It looks to me like you are referring to @FlorianDiesch's solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I used: find /home/folder -name *.dat -exec sed -i -E 's/-?0[.]/(four_spaces)&/2' {} \;, but it didn't work for many lines. Not sure why, I couldn't find any pattern in it.

Comment: @Hunter If you can show me some sample lines that it didn't work on, I'd be interested.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some sample lines.

Comment: I've checked it with `find /home/folder -name \*.dat -exec sed -i -E 's/-?[[:digit:]][.]/     &/2' {} \;` and it is indeed working now! +1 and thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

find the first dot :)

```
sed -r 's/(.*\.[^-\.]*)(-?)0\.(.*)/\1\t\20.\3/' file
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `(some chars)` save `some chars` to reference later
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\.` literal `.`
- `[^-\.]` any characters except hyphen or `.`
- `-?` optional `-`
- `\1\t\20.\3` print the saved patterns, a tab, and `0.` in the correct places

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$ sed -E 's/(-?0\.[0-9]+)(-?0\.[0-9]+)/\1\t\2/' file
-0.0999999999999659     -0.0000000006287859
-0.0899999999999750     0.8000000006183942
-0.0799999999999841     -0.0000000007463807
-0.0699999999999932     0.0000000008661516
-0.0600000000000023     0.0000000008640644
-0.0500000000000114     0.0000000008807621
-0.0400000000000205     -0.7000000009575896
-0.0299999999999727     0.0000000009476864
-0.0199999999999818     0.0000000009150902
-0.0099999999999909     0.0000000008144152
0.0000000000000000      0.0000000007097434
0.0099999999999909      0.0000000007847500
0.0199999999999818      0.0000000009030998
0.0300000000000296      0.0000000009741985
```

How it works:

- `-?0\.[0-9]+` match `0.` followed by one or more other decimal digits and optionally preceded by `-`
- `(-?0\.[0-9]+)(-?0\.[0-9]+)` capture 2 instances of the above
- `\1\t\2` substitute them back with a TAB in between